# Bloc transformEvents called only once

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm making a search function that calls events every `TextFormField` Onchanged and trying to add debouncer to limit its api calls. I'm trying this code from this [link](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1107). When I type and wait for 1 second its working. But when I continue to add another letter nothing happens. It doesn't even trigger the `mapEventToState` and `transformEvents` function when I added a break to it. I'm using flutter_bloc: ^6.1.3

TextFormField:

```
TextFieldTemplate(
onChanged: (value) 
{
    search = _searchController.text;
     BlocProvider.of<ListBloc>(context).add(
          SearchListEvent(
              search: search,
              limit: PAGE_SIZE,
              offset: pageKey));
},
),
```

Bloc:

```
@override
Stream<Transition<ListEvent, ListState>>
  transformEvents(Stream<ListEvent> events, transitionFn) {
final defferedEvents = events
    .where((e) => e is SearchListEvent)
    .debounceTime(const Duration(seconds: 1))
    .distinct()
    .switchMap(transitionFn);
final forwardedEvents = events
    .where((e) => e is! SearchListEvent)
    .asyncExpand(transitionFn);
return forwardedEvents.mergeWith([defferedEvents]);
}


@override
Stream<ListState> mapEventToState(ListEvent event,) async* {
if (event is SearchListEvent) {
  yield ListLoadInProgressState();
  final failureOrSearch = await getProduct(Params(
    search: event.search,
    offset: event.offset,
    limit: event.limit,
  ));
  yield* _eitherLoadedOrErrorState(failureOrSearch);
} 
}
```

Comment: Hi, [Does this answer your question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367800/flutter-bloc-does-not-change-textformfield-initialvalue)

Comment: I suppose that _searchController not added to your search text field. You can also use `value` from onChanged callback instead: `BlocProvider.of<ListBloc>(context).add(SearchListEvent(search: value, limit: PAGE_SIZE, offset: pageKey));`

Comment: @Mol0ko My only problem was the `transformEvents` to add `debouncer` to not spam API every `Onchanged`. If I remove `transformEvents` function in the bloc, everything thing works.

Comment: @unice is your problem solved? or you still need to debounce SearchListEvent?

Comment: @Mol0ko Its not yet solved, I need the debouncer in the bloc. But like I said in the question above, it only triggers in the first search.

Comment: @unice Ok. Could you provide code of your SearchListEvent? I suppose that it is not Equatable and distinct() operator filters all events as same

Comment: I think its already solved. I just commented the .distinct() and it works for now. Don't know if that's the fix but will test it for a while. This will only debounce the `SearchListEvent` and will  not debounce other events just like what I wanted. Thanks guys