# TextField and BLoC - value not updated or keyboard dismissed

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-textinputfield

I want to use a `TextField` in combination with [BLoC package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) in Flutter. The aim is to keep the content of the `TextField` in sync with the respective property of the BLoC.

Because BLoC is based on a `BlocBuilder` widget that basically subscribes to a `Stream` and updates and re-renders all affected child widgets when the `Stream` emits something new, I thought the following approach would be sufficient:

```
BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
        TextFormField(
          initialValue: state.model.title,
          onChanged: (String value) => myCubit.setTitle(value),
        ),
    }
);
```

And actually, it's working. The problems appear when I want to be able to override the value from the BLoC. In my case, I have a `TextField` and a select field (`DropdownButton`). When the user selects a value from the `DropdownButton`, the content of the `TextField` is supposed to be overridden.
With the above approach, when I call `setTitle(value)` in the `onChange` of the `DropdownButton`, the value in the `Cubit` is overridden, but the `TextField` is left unchanged.

Then I had the idea to use a `TextEditingController` that handles the text of the `TextField` (like it's suggested [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2293) by Felix Angelov), updates the `Cubit` on change and listens to external changes to the respective value in the `Cubit`:

```
BlocConsumer<MyCubit, MyState>(
    listener: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
        if (state is InitialState) {
            _controller.addListener(() {
              myCubit.setTitle(_controller.text);
            });
            return;
        }

        _controller.text = state.title;
    },
    builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
        TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
        ), 
    }
);
```

If I do this, then the initial value is correctly set by the `Cubit`, the value is updated in the `TextField` when I change it using the `DropdownButton` and it's updated in the Cubit when the text in the `TextField` changes. However, there is one problem: every time I enter a character inside the `TextField`, it loses its focus.
`autofocus: true` to the rescue? Unfortunately not. This prevents to lose focus, but then it jumps to the first character of the entered text whenever I enter something. Also, I don't want the `TextField` to have focus initially. Setting a `FocusNode` also does not help.
Even setting a `UniqueKey` like it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367800/flutter-bloc-does-not-change-textformfield-initialvalue) does not change something.
The ideas presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586892/flutter-textformfield-hidden-by-keyboard) regarding `FocusNode` and `onEditingComplete` did not solve my problem either.

Does anyone have a working solution for a TextField in combination with BLoC that fulfills the following requirements:

- When something in the `TextField` is entered, the BLoC/Cubit is updated accordingly
- When the BloC/Cubit is updated, the `TextField`'s content is updated accordingly
- There is no unexpected, annoying keyboard dismiss behavior or `TextField` losing its focus
- The `TextField` can have an initial value but does not have to be focussed on render

I could not find a solution despite having researched for quite some time now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your later attempt to change `TextField` text using `TextEditingController` why your `TextField` is wrapped inside `BlocBuilder`? I believe this would work correctly for updating `TextField`'s text from your BLoC:

```
BlocListener<MyCubit, MyState>(
  listener: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
    if(state.title != _controller.text) {
      _controller.text = state.title;
      _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: state.title.length);
    }
  },
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
  ),
);
```

And for updating value inside of your BLoC with events coming from your `TextField`, register a listener to the `TextEditingController` in your `initState`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.addListener(_changed);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.removeListener(_changed);
  super.dispose();
}

_changed() {
  myCubit.setTitle(_controller.text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. If I follow your advice, then the cursor inside the `TextField` is reset whenever I enter a character (like I have described in the question). That's probably because what you inserted in the listener (`_controller.text = state.title;`) is executed on *every* change, causing the TextField to re-render and the cursor to be placed at the start.

Comment: Check my answer again, I've just updated code inside listener. @Schnodderbalken

Comment: Checking whether the property of the cubit differs from the entered text is actually pretty smart! The part with `_controller.selection` is not even needed. I just found out a different approach: emitting a different `State` when the cubit property is set. Then in the listener check for `if (state is! TextChangedFromTextField)`. But your if condition is simpler and better. Very good :). Later this day, I will test a bit and if everything's fine, I will accept! @Amir_P

Comment: Glad that if worked out ;) @Schnodderbalken

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code for `TextField` is correct, except that you can use a `TextEditingController` to set its initial value. You can set the initial value of the controller inside `initState`, so you need to use a stateful widget.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final state = BlocProvider.of<MyCubit>(context, listen: false);
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: state.model.title);
  }
```

```
BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
        TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          onChanged: (String value) => myCubit.setTitle(value),
        ),
    }
);
```

In the `onChanged` of the `DropdownButton`, in addition to calling `setTitle(value)` on the cubit, change the value of the `TextField` using its `controller`.

```
(value){
    myCubit.setTitle(value);
    _controller.text = value;
}
```

The only problem that may still be unsolved is when calling `_controller.text = value;` the cursor moves to the beginning --before the first character.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately the behavior of the cursor jumping to the beginning makes the whole `TextField` unusable as the user is unable to enter any text without disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, without using the `TextSelection.collapsed(offset: state.title.length)`, which limits the textfield functionality.

The controller should be defined in the state, not in the `build` function, and initialized in the `initState()`. If you call the `addListener` in the `build` function, it will re-initialize the controller after every keypress.

```
  late TextEditingController inputController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inputController = TextEditingController();
    inputController.addListener(textListener);
  }

  void textListener() {
    context.read<TextCubit>().textChanged(text: inputController.text);
  }
```

In the `build` function inside the `BlocListener` the `inputcontroller.text` should be updated if the state changes.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocListener<TextCubit, String>(listener: (_, text) {
    if (inputController.text != text) {
      inputController.text = text;
    }
  }, child:
    Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: TextField(
        controller: inputController,
      ),
    )
  ));
}
```

Comment: Only problem is, that if you reset the value programatically from one of your events in BLoC, the state won't update in the TextField and you'll still have the "old" value