# Flutter TextField\TextFormField initialization value with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I do not know English well, so I will hope for a translator)
P.S I am new to the world of flutter and dart, I am a .net and angular developer.
*In my application, I refuse to use StatefullWidget in favor of Flutter_Bloc, so if I need to change the state in the stream, then it will be more like a StreamBuilder.*
I ran into a problem: I have a widget that uses TextField or TextFormField, it doesn't matter to me what to use, at the moment I have functionality in the first place, not design, as the deadlines are burning (for the university). I want to initialize the data from the Bloc that gets there from the BlocProvider after the event that receives the data from my backend application is fired. If you use a TextFormField, it has an initialValue property, if you write state.Title there, then I see the following picture through the debugger: initially the state has what I wrote for the block in Super, and there, in fact, everything is null, but after literally a moment (some then the number of milliseconds) its state is updated after the initialization event: bloc..add(event), but an empty value got into initialValue and is not redrawn, I don’t know how best to make this behavior for me so that the value is initialized in the text field and subsequently changed together with state update.
In my application, I did a thing that I don’t like - I set up a variable and inside the StreamBuilder through the TextEditingController I change the text inside the text field, and when I click on the save button, I send this value, but I want it to interact with the state and update every time. I'm attaching an example of the code where I'm facing the problem.

*ParentWidget*

```
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => PlanStageDetailBloc()..add(PlanStageDetailInitialEvent(planId, id)),
      child: BlocBuilder<PlanStageDetailBloc, PlanStageDetailInitialState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          final bloc = context.read<PlanStageDetailBloc>();
          return RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () async => bloc.add(PlanStageDetailInitialEvent(planId, id)),
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: ConstantColors.mainMenuBtn,
                  title: const Text('Test text'),
                body: const PlanStageDetailScreen(),
```

*ChildWidget*

```
class PlanStageDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlanStageDetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Flexible(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.9,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 40),
                      child: _PlanDropdownButton(),
                    ))),
            const Flexible(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    widthFactor: 0.9,
                    child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 40), child: _TitleTextField())))
```

*TitleTextFieldWidget*

```
class _TitleTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TitleTextField();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocBuilder<PlanStageDetailBloc, PlanStageDetailInitialState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return TextFormField(
            obscureText: false,
            initialValue: state.title,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            onChanged: (text) => context.read<PlanStageDetailBloc>().add(ChangeTitle(text)),
            onFieldSubmitted: (value) => context.read<PlanStageDetailBloc>().add(ChangeTitle(value)),
            decoration:
                TextFormFieldStyle.textFieldStyle(labelTextStr: 'Title*', hintTextStr: 'Enter title'));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*Partial PlanStageDetailBloc.dart*

```
class PlanStageDetailBloc extends Bloc<PlanStageDetailEvent, PlanStageDetailInitialState> {
  PlanStageDetailBloc() : super(PlanStageDetailInitialState._(id: 0)) {
    on<PlanStageDetailInitialEvent>(_onInit);
    on<ChangeDate>(_onChangeDate);
    on<ChangeTitle>(_onChangeTitle);
    on<ChangeData>(_onChangeData);
    on<ChangeStatus>(_onChangeStatus);
    on<ChangePriority>(_onChangePriority);
    on<ChangeParentPlan>(_onChangeParentPlan);
  }
```

I accept constructive criticism, as well as good suggestions for improving my code), but most importantly I want to see options for solving this problem

I expect that after initializing the widget, my Bloc will receive all the necessary data and display them in my fields if the data corresponding to the field exists, in order to further correct or change them along with the Bloc state change, and send the changed data to my backend so that my data has been updated in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching for a solution to the problem for a while, talked to ChatGPT, and here's what I found. It seemed like a good solution to me, but I haven't tested it on systems other than Android yet. However, it works perfectly on Android.
*PlanStageDetail.dart*

```
class PlanStageDetailWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlanStageDetailWidget({super.key, required this.planId, required this.title, required this.id});

  final num planId;
  final num id;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => PlanStageDetailBloc()..add(PlanStageDetailInitialEvent(planId, id)),
      child: BlocBuilder<PlanStageDetailBloc, PlanStageDetailInitialState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          final bloc = context.read<PlanStageDetailBloc>();

          TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController(text: state.title);
          titleController.value = titleController.value.copyWith(
              text: bloc.state.title,
              selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: bloc.state.title.length)));

          TextEditingController dataController = TextEditingController(text: state.data);
          dataController.value = dataController.value.copyWith(
              text: bloc.state.data,
              selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: bloc.state.data.length)));

          return RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () async => bloc.add(PlanStageDetailInitialEvent(planId, id)),
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: ConstantColors.mainMenuBtn,
                  title: Row(children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => context
                              .read<HomeAuthNavCubit>()
                              .changePageRoute(PlanStagesList(planId: planId), 'Планы', 4),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded)),
                    ),
                    Text(title)
                  ]),
                ),
                body: Center(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Flexible(
                              child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                  widthFactor: 0.9,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                    child: _PlanDropdownButton(),
                                  ))),
                          Flexible(
                              child: FractionallySizedBox(
                                  widthFactor: 0.9,
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                          controller: titleController,
                                          obscureText: false,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                          onChanged: (text) {
                                            bloc.add(ChangeTitle(text));
                                          },
                                          decoration: TextFormFieldStyle.textFieldStyle(
                                              labelTextStr: 'Наименование *', hintTextStr: 'Введите наименование')))))
```

Comment: The truth is, you need to carefully consider returning the focus to the position from which the user started editing the text.

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior can be achieved by directly accessing the public state of the `TextFormField` and updating it in response to the Bloc event. We can update it in response to a Bloc event by using a `BlocListener` instead of a `BlocBuilder`.

Step by step:

1. Define the Bloc events. In this scenario, I will define a single `InitializeApi` event to trigger some asynchronous work.

Code:

```
/// Base class for [ApiBloc] events.
abstract class ApiEvent {
  const ApiEvent();
}

/// This event is used to trigger API initialization.
class InitializeApi extends ApiEvent {
  const InitializeApi();
}
```

2. We need the Bloc states that our `TextFormField` will respond to. This includes an uninitialized state `ApiPendingInitialization` (not necessary, only included for clarity), and a `ApiInitialized` state for when the asynchronous operation is completed.

Code:

```
/// Base class for [ApiBloc] states.
abstract class ApiState {
  const ApiState();
}

/// Intermediary state for unitialized [ApiBloc] instances.
class ApiPendingInitialization extends ApiState {
  const ApiPendingInitialization();
}

/// State indicating that the [ApiBloc] is ready/initialized.
class ApiInitialized extends ApiState {
  ApiInitialized(this.title);

  final String title;
}
```

3. A simple `ApiBloc` which is configured for our previous classes. It defaults to `ApiPendingInitialization` until the `InitializeApi` event is added to the Bloc.

Code:

```
class ApiBloc extends Bloc<ApiEvent, ApiState> {
  ApiBloc() : super(const ApiPendingInitialization()) {
    on<InitializeApi>(_initializeApi);
  }
  
  /// Initialize the API. Simulate asynchronous work.
  Future<void> _initializeApi(
    InitializeApi event,
    Emitter<ApiState> emit,
  ) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    emit(ApiInitialized("API Response Title"));
  }
}
```

4. Now that the Bloc boilerplate is complete, we will create our `Widget` to hook it up with the `TextFormField`. This will simply be called `ApiConsumer`.

Code:

```
class ApiConsumer extends StatelessWidget {
  const ApiConsumer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// This key will be used to access the TextFormField state.
    ///
    /// The TextFormField state is of type FormFieldState<String>, so that is
    /// the generic type of this GlobalKey.
    final textFormFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();

    final textFormField = BlocListener<ApiBloc, ApiState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        /// If the state is not ApiInitialized, then there is no data. Return.
        if (state is! ApiInitialized) return;

        /// The state must be ApiInitialized here, and ApiInitialized has data:
        /// the title property.
        textFormFieldKey.currentState?.didChange(state.title);
      },
      child: TextFormField(
        key: textFormFieldKey, // Make sure to pass the key.
        obscureText: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          label: Text('Title*'),
          hintText: 'Enter title',
        ),
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: textFormField)));
  }
}
```

5. Finally, the entry point should be self-explanatory.

Code:

```
runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => ApiBloc()..add(const InitializeApi()),
      child: const ApiConsumer(),
    ),
  );
```

When you run this program, you will see that the `TextFormField` will update to the API response value "API Response Title" after the simulated asynchronous work inside `_initializeApi` is complete.

**Note:**

By using the `BlocListener` widget, the `ApiConsumer` widget itself never rebuilds. However, the `TextFormField` does rebuild, because it is a `StatefulWidget` and its `didChange` method internally calls `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this widget based on this question [TextField and BLoC - value not updated or keyboard dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625943/textfield-and-bloc-value-not-updated-or-keyboard-dismissed)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class BlocTextFormField<TBloc extends StateStreamable<TState>, TState> extends StatefulWidget {
  const BlocTextFormField({
    required this.selector,
    this.initialValue,
    this.onChanged,
    this.decoration,
    this.keyboardType,
    this.inputFormatters,
    super.key,
  });

  final String? initialValue;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final InputDecoration? decoration;
  final String? Function(TState value) selector;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;

  @override
  State<BlocTextFormField<TBloc, TState>> createState() => _BlocTextFormFieldState<TBloc, TState>();
}

class _BlocTextFormFieldState<TBloc extends StateStreamable<TState>, TState>
    extends State<BlocTextFormField<TBloc, TState>> {
  _BlocTextFormFieldState();

  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<TBloc, TState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        String? text = widget.selector(state);

        if (text != null && text != _controller.text) {
          _controller.text = text;
          _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: (text).length);
        }
      },
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: widget.decoration,
        onTapOutside: (e) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialValue);
    _controller.addListener(_changed);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_changed);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _changed() {
    widget.onChanged?.call(_controller.text);
  }
}
```

Use:

```
BlocTextFormField<OrderAddressDetailBloc, OrderAddressDetailState>(
                selector: (state) => state.entranceNumber?.toString(),
                initialValue: state.entranceNumber?.toString(),
                onChanged: (entranceNumber) => context
                    .read<OrderAddressDetailBloc>()
                    .add(OrderAddressDetailEvent.entranceNumberChanged(entranceNumber)),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: context.appTexts.order_entrance_number_title,
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3), FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              ),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**